# Is there a better way to format this date field in Crystal Reports? Im having trouble with a scheduling program and getting the correct data

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a program that runs reports on a schedule. For some reason the data it pulls is not the same as what Crystal Reports pulls. I was told it has to do with the way that the PO Enter Date field is formatted. It pulls fine from Crystal Reports but the scheduler shows different data. Im not sure where to go from here.

'''

```
 (IF(LENGTH(TOTEXT({POP.PODADD}))=9)
        THEN (DateSerial ((TONUMBER("20"+Mid 
    (Totext({POP.PODADD}),4,2))),
                        (TONUMBER(LEFT(TOTEXT({POP.PODADD}),1))),
                        (TONUMBER(MID(TOTEXT({POP.PODADD}),2,2)))))
        ELSE (DateSerial ((TONUMBER("20"+Mid 
    (Totext({POP.PODADD}),5,2))),
                        (TONUMBER(LEFT(TOTEXT({POP.PODADD}),2))),
                        (TONUMBER(MID(TOTEXT({POP.PODADD}),3,2))))))
```

'''

Comment: From where data is "pulled" - from some kind of database perhaps? If yes, then what is actual field type in database? What means "shows different data" - show us some examples!

Comment: So i looked into the database field. Its actually a number. ??? The data in the table is 10,112.00, 10,212,00..... it takes the number and turns it into a date.

Comment: And what is different in output data? What this 10,112.00 does mean anyway? For Crystal, I would create SQL query, converting such numbers into proper date - then you can format them more easily, all such `ToText()` functions tend to be very region/locale sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

The Crystal Runtime doesn't always "follow" custom formatting defined in Crystal Designer.
If you need a specific formatting, convert the date to formatted text using a formula such as:

```
ToText({POP.PODADD}, 'yyyyMMdd')
```

The 2nd argument gives you control over the desired formatting.